# Save editable div-tag content into an object?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I have an editable div-tag where i dynamically create paragraphs. I want to save that div-tags content on button click. Is that possible?

```
   <div id="RiskScoreTextArea" class="RiskScoreTextArea" contenteditable="true">
                    <p id="textAreaP"></p>
                </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use jquery for that

```
$('.btnClick').on('click', function(){
    var content = $('#RiskScoreTextArea').html();
});
```

If you wanted the text of the div you can use .text() but html will return the full contents of the div.  Hopefully this will work for you.